# Can't get value of a textbox inside panel

Tags: javascript

I don't now why I can't get the value of this control. I've tried two things, what am I doing wrong?

The value in the textbox is not null (there is a value, set in page_load).

My textfield:

```
 asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlInstruments" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:Panel ID="plStore" runat="server" GroupingText="Store">
       <div style="margin: 5px;">
       <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" SkinID="header2NonBoldSkin" Text="Reval date" /><br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" />
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnStore" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;Store&nbsp;&nbsp;" OnClick="btnStore_Click" 
           OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to store data for ' + getRevalDate() +'?');" />
  </asp:Panel>
 </ContentTemplate>     
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

JS (value is null), the element is null...:

```
function getRevalDate() {
        return document.getElementById('<%= txtText.ClientID %>').value;
    }
```

Did also try this (same result):

```
function getRevalDate() {
        return document.getElementById('<%= plStore.FindControl("txtText").ClientID %>').value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the panel inside the updatepanel and a contenttemplate. Therefore it'll be refreshing the contents of the updatepanel on postback.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePannel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="plStore" runat="server" GroupingText="Store">
       <div style="margin: 5px;">
       <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" SkinID="header2NonBoldSkin" Text="Reval date" /><br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" />
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnStore" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;Store&nbsp;&nbsp;" OnClick="btnStore_Click" 
           OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to store data for ' + getRevalDate() +'?');" />
  </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Sorry for leaving some facts out. The Panel is inside a UpdatePanel and a ContentTemplare

Comment: It should be working! maybe remove the UpdateMode="Conditional", I thought the problem is with the fact that the panel is not inside an updatePanel, but it is already there!